# Как создать список?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

```
import random
card_deck = {
    1: "6 пик",
    2: "6 треф",
    3: "6 бубен",
    4: "6 червей",
    5: "7 пик",
    6: "7 треф"
}

numbers = range(1, 7)
player = random.sample(numbers, 6)
for i in player:
    cards_player = card_deck.get(i)  # вернуть значение по ключю
print("Ваши карты:", cards_player)
```

Как сделать чтобы переменная `cards_player` отображала все 6 значений?

Comment: в 3+ версиях уже давно есть генераторы и списки. Проще юзать их.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random


card_deck={1:"6 пик",2:"6 треф",3:"6 бубен",4:"6 червей",
       5:"7 пик",6:"7 треф"}

numbers = range(1,7)
player=random.sample(numbers,6)

cards_player = []
for i in player:
    cards_player.append(card_deck.get(i))
print("Ваши карты: ", ', '.join(cards_player))
```

Или ещё проще:

```
import random


card_deck=['7 треф', '6 бубен', '6 червей', '6 пик', '7 пик', '6 треф']
cards_player = random.sample(card_deck, 6)

print("Ваши карты: ", ', '.join(cards_player))
```